# 100 requests/second with multiple indexes results in server load of 25 in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, rdbms, database-performance, database-indexes

I have an application which is using oracle database on 8 core machine and 16Gb RAM. The table have 15 columns and  around 5700,000 rows. There are indexes on 5 columns which are frequently updated. When we put a load of 100 requests/second which is insert query and then there is some read and update operation going on every request loop , the CPU loads start increasing exponentially and reaches upto 25 and after that I start getting error

```
I/O Error : Socket read time out.
```

However when we perform same operations with indexes on single column then the load remains consistent to 4-5. Though Indexing on 5 columns and having machine of 8 core CPU and 16 Gb RAM , the load must not have that much difference.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.  Adding indexes creates overhead-- those indexes need to be maintained when data is inserted and updated.  Indexes on frequently updated columns have a relatively large amount of overhead.  You seem to be saying that your load tests confirm these expectations.  There is no magical "use exactly the same indexes but maintain them more efficiently" flag.  No idea whether you need to reconsider the indexes you think you want, the hardware you're trying to use, the application design, or something else.

Comment: @JustinCave thanks for you reply. If I insert a row in database , table indexes are updated. Does it means that all indexes are rearranged in B-Tree ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "rearranged".  Inserting a new row may involve things like block splits which might be what you're talking about.

Comment: @JustinCave my question is if I have index on one column load is consistent and fine. but if i have index on 5 column load on server increases exponentially to 25  and I started getting I/O error , the server configuration is 8 core machine and 16 Gb RAm. Does indexes can have that much overload that most of time utilizes by database in indexes maintenance.

Comment: If you are asking "Is it possible that during a load test that my application is spending most of its time maintaining indexes?" that is certainly possible.  That sounds like what you are describing.  Of course, without actual data, it's rather hard to confirm anything.

Comment: If you have an enterprise edition and the performance and tuning pack license you could use an AWR report to check what the cause of that load is. Or just check the ASH views directly for the most frequent wait events. A CPU bound database usually means some hotspots for synchronization on the buffer cache or related memory areas. _Maybe_ it's index contention that _could_ be improved with a reverse index if the primary key is created by a sequence. _Maybe_ it's a contention on the sequence. Maybe it's something entirely different

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could show DDL for the creation of the table and the creation of your five indexes.  It would also be helpful to understand what each indexed column represents, what the distribution of that data looks like, how unique are the values, how frequently a column is updated vs being inserted, etc.  The accuracy of answers depends greatly on the clarity of your question.  There are knobs you can turn on index creation that might help your performance issues, but there is not enough information here to offer any assistance.